# Submodules preventing me from staging files in git

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am trying to create a small react application. I have the git CLI installed on my computer.

Once I use create-react-app and it finishes loading, I immediately use git init in the terminal. I then immediately use git add .  , but I instantly get the following message:

```
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> nodule
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached nodule
hint: 
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

Even though I haven't actually written any code in this project or even opened any of the file, I still go through the process using the git rm command. And even after that, I still cannot get any files to stage using the git add command. I'm not sure what im doing wrong.

Comment: Did you `cd` into the app folder that create-react-app makes?

Comment: Yes. If i used create-react-app my-app to create the project, i would then cd into the my-app folder.